# resizing a UIControl in an animated fashion

Tags: ios

I have created a button which I want to expand/contract. I found a way to get the x,y coordinates along with width and height. Using these I call CGRectMake function to redraw the button. I am trying to figure out how to redraw in an animated fashion. Below is my attempt but I am almost sure that there are better ways of doing this. Any comments?

```
   pointX = navigateBtn.frame.origin.x;
   pointY = navigateBtn.frame.origin.y;
   height = CGRectGetHeight(navigateBtn.frame);
   width = CGRectGetWidth(navigateBtn.frame);
   for (int i=1;i<=800000;i++) {
      int k=i/100000;
      navigateBtn.frame=CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, width, height*k);
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to know is what the destination `rect` will be and then you can animate like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{
                     navigateBtn.frame = endFrame;
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Don't try to animate things yourself.

Use UIView animation. A good tutorial is available from Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

But to be perfectly honest you should probably start with an introductory iOS programming book. The way you phrased your question makes me think that you still have a lot of fundamentals to learn.